# Magicsuggest change selection programmatically

Tags: selection, magicsuggest

I've been working with MagicSuggestion for a couple of days:

```
<div>
     <div id="magicsuggest"></div>
 </div>

VehicleNameList = [{id: 1, name: "Volvo"},
                   {id: 2, name: "Audi"},
                   {id: 3, name: "Volkswagen"}]

vehicleNameSelected = "Volvo"

magicVehicleChange = $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
                        data: VehicleNameList,
                        placeholder: function () {
                            $('.ms-sel-ctn input').attr("placeholder", vehicleNameSelected);
                        }
                    });


 $(magicVehicleChange).on('selectionchange', function (e, m, sel) {
                    if (sel.length == 0) return;
                    for (i = 0; i < VehicleNameList.length; i++) {
                        if (typeof sel[0] != 'undefined')
                            if (VehicleNameList[i].name == sel[0].name) {
                                vehicleNameSelected(sel[0].name);
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    if (typeof sel[0] != 'undefined') {
                        magicVehicleChange.collapse();
                        this.clear();
                    }
                });
```

The problem is that I want to change the selected vehicle name when a button is changed, for example to "Volkswagen", by calling:

```
magicVehicleChange.setValue([{ name: "Volkswagen", value: 3 }])
```

but without success. What an I doing wrong? Is there a way to change the selection when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change:

```
magicVehicleChange.setValue([{ name: "Volkswagen", value: 3 }])
```

to

```
magicVehicleChange.setSelection([{ id: 3, name: "Volkswagen" }])
```